# Can I get a column formula for a fusion table from the API

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to backup one of my fusion tables and would like to be able to use the API to do so.  The trouble is I am not able to get the formula for a particular column, just the values.

I'm able to describe the table and see the column info (id, name, and type) and then do a SELECT and get all the information in the table, but what comes back is the value, not the formula.  Is there any way I can get the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the formula in a column from the API. Please feel free to open a feature request on the list:

http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list