# Can a fusion table query update a column to contain the merged contents of another two columns

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with the location in a lat and long column using the v2 API.

I want to combine these into a single LOCATION column called latlong.

Although there is web support to [Combine multi-column locations](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/175922?hl=en), 
the [Fusion Table API V2 Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables) says:

> You cannot use the API to programmatically modify columns that are
>   two-column locations, but you can use the Fusion Tables web application to
>   modify this once the table has been created.

It also says a fusion table needs a LOCATION column to perform spatial queries.

```
"columns": [
{
    "name": "lat",
    "type": "NUMBER"
},
{
    "name": "long",
    "type": "NUMBER"
}
{
    "name": "latlong",
    "type": "LOCATION"
}
```

Is there a fusiontable query to concatenate the lat and long numbers into a string and update it in the empty table?
I can't work out the syntax for the UPDATE query where the value is the result of the lat and long.

For example

```
rows =  service.query().sql(sql="SELECT * FROM %s" % (tableid)).execute()
newtable = service.query().sql(sql="UPDATE %s SET latlong = lat ' ' long WHERE ROWID=%s" % (tableid, rows)).execute()
```

This won't work because rows is to long for a valid url.

Is it possible to use the Fusion Tables Rest API to define a [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489765/can-i-get-a-column-formula-for-a-fusion-table-from-the-api) in the latlong column or is there some other work around this limitation?

One alternative is to manipulate the lat and long data into a single column before creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this thing in Fusion Table Rows Section. Just add a new formula column and put formula as ('lat'&" "&'lng').. need not to do all these sql stuff

Comment: I don't think a formula column can be a location column, only a number
https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/178196